# Two Cordova plugins using Firebase.Core framework causing conflicts when building application

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to use two cordova plugins within my Ionic application:

1. Firebase: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase
2. Firebase Dynamic Links: https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks

When attempting to build my application, I run in to an error that I believe has to do with Firebase.Core being requested in two locations and (possibly) using different versions(?). On build, I get the following error (there's a ton of these so here's one, let me know if you need all):

```
duplicate symbol _FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotificationTokenKey in:
    /Users/jordan/Downloads/ReleaseHub/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libFirebaseCore.a(FIRApp.o)
    ReleaseHub/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(FIRApp.o)
```

When looking at the `plugin.xml` for each, I see that Firebase has:

`<framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseCore.framework" />`

While Dynamic Links has:

`<framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.0"/>`

Thus I am led to believe that this is where the conflict sits, due to the "duplicate" variable. Am I on the right track? How do I get these two plugins to play nicely with each other? Thanks!

And just to clarify, when I remove the dynamic links package from my project, the project builds as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solved it by replacing cordova-plugin-firebase with this forked plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.

Maybe you can give it a try.